# Is it OK to ask about experiences where users were targeted?

Tags: discussion

I recently read about the distinction between *generic* vs *targeted* attacks, where *generic* attacks are ones where an attacker casts a wide net and makes a catch, while *targeted* attacks are those that hone in on an individual, group, or organization.

I was wondering if it would be OK to start a thread about this latter type of attack, inviting users to share their experiences. I was hesitant to post it initially, largely because the question I typed was flagged as subjective. However, after reading the [guidelines](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), it seems like a legitimate question, because it would:

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
- tend to have long, not short, answers
- *invite sharing experiences over opinions*
- are more than just mindless social fun

Perhaps there would be issues with citing facts and references, but I don't know if this would be a disqualifier for asking such a question. Please let me know if such a topic is out-of-bounds. It will not be posted unless someone gives me the green light.

Thanks.

Comment: "starting threads" as a concept is not going to work here. This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Q&A site, there needs to be the possibility of having a single acceptable answer. "Please tell me your experiences" cannot have an "Answer" per se.

On the page you linked:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here.